# OR-tools routing fails to find 'trivial' optimal solution in the presence of order-constraints

Tags: python, or-tools

In order to better understand the constraint-programming behind or-tools routing, I created a toy example of a depot and 4 other nodes configured to allow for two routes.

[image]

The idea is that a vehicle travels from the depot `0` to `1`, then either picks `2` or `3`, continues to `4` and returns to the depot `0`; the vehicle either picks the green or red path. My actual problem is more complicated and has multiple vehicles, but has similar constraints.

For this example I created a euclidean-distance function for the cost:

```py
class Distances:
    def __init__(self):
        self.locations = [
            [-1,  0], # source
            [ 0, -1], # waypoint 1
            [ 0,  1], # waypoint 2
            [ 1,  0], # destination
        ]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.locations) + 1

    def dist(self, x, y):
        return int(10000 * math.sqrt(
            (x[0] - y[0]) ** 2 +
            (x[1] - y[1]) ** 2))

    def __call__(self, i, j):
        if i == 0 and j == 0:
            return 0
        if j == 0 or i == 0:
            return 1 # very small distance between depot and non-depot, simulating 0
        return self.dist(self.locations[i - 1], self.locations[j - 1])


distance = Distances()
```

And a l0 distance function to constraint the order:

```py
# l0-distance to add order constraints
class Order:
    def __call__(self, i, j):
        return 0 if i == j else 1


order = Order()
```

Then I create the model and try to solve this:

```py
search_parameters = pywrapcp.RoutingModel.DefaultSearchParameters()
search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.ALL_UNPERFORMED)

search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.SIMULATED_ANNEALING
search_parameters.time_limit_ms = 3000

routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(len(distance), 1)

routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(distance)
routing.SetDepot(0)
solver = routing.solver()

routing.AddDimension(order, int(1e18), int(1e18), True, "order")

# Since `ALL_UNPERFORMED` is used, each node must be allowed inactive
order_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie("order")
routing.AddDisjunction([1], int(1e10))
routing.AddDisjunction([2, 3], int(1e10))
routing.AddDisjunction([4], int(1e10))

solver.AddConstraint(order_dimension.CumulVar(1) <= order_dimension.CumulVar(2))
solver.AddConstraint(order_dimension.CumulVar(1) <= order_dimension.CumulVar(3))

solver.AddConstraint(order_dimension.CumulVar(2) <= order_dimension.CumulVar(4))
solver.AddConstraint(order_dimension.CumulVar(3) <= order_dimension.CumulVar(4))

# routing.AddPickupAndDelivery(1, 2)
# routing.AddPickupAndDelivery(1, 3)
# routing.AddPickupAndDelivery(2, 4)
# routing.AddPickupAndDelivery(3, 4)

routing.CloseModelWithParameters(search_parameters)
assignment = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

if assignment is not None:
    print('cost: ' + str(assignment.ObjectiveValue()))
    route = []
    index = routing.Start(0)
    while not routing.IsEnd(index):
        route.append(routing.IndexToNode(index))
        index = assignment.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
    for node in route:
        print(' - {:2d}'.format(node))
else:
    print('nothing found')
```

So `[1]` and `[4]` are disjunctions to allow for `ALL_UNPERFORMED` first solution to work, and the disjunction `[2, 3]` to state that either the green or red path should be chosen.

With these disjunctions the solver finds a solution, but if I add that `2`  and `3` should be visited after `1` and before `4`, the solver does not visit `2` or `3` at all. Why is this the case? Why can't the solver find the more optimal route `0 -> 1 -> 2/3 -> 4 -> 0` avoiding the `int(1e10)` disjunction penalty for `[2,3]`?

**EDIT:**

Soft-constraining the order-constraints by removing them and adding to `Distance.__call__`:

```py
if (i == 2 or j == 1) or (i == 3 or j == 1) or (i == 4 or j == 2) or (i == 4 or j == 3):
    return int(1e10)
```

to penalize a disallowed order, results in the route `0 -> 2 -> 1 -> 4 -> 0`. So I wonder why or-tools won't swap `1` and `2`, even when explicitly enabling `use_swap_active` and `use_relocate_neighbors` in `search_parameters.local_search_operators`.

**NOTE:** Failed because it should have been:

```py
if (i == 2 and j == 1) or (i == 3 and j == 1) or (i == 4 and j == 2) or (i == 4 and j == 3):
    return int(1e10)
```

Concluding: the search-space is small, a better solution is in the neighborhood of `use_relocate_neighbors` of the returned solution, yet or-tools does not find it. Why?

## All code:

```py
import pandas
import os.path

import numpy
import math
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2


class Distances:
    def __init__(self):
        self.locations = [
            [-1,  0], # source
            [ 0, -1], # waypoint 1
            [ 0,  1], # waypoint 2
            [ 1,  0], # destination
        ]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.locations) + 1

    def dist(self, x, y):
        return int(10000 * math.sqrt(
            (x[0] - y[0]) ** 2 +
            (x[1] - y[1]) ** 2))

    def __call__(self, i, j):
        if i == 0 and j == 0:
            return 0
        if j == 0 or i == 0:
            return 1 # very small distance between depot and non-depot, simulating 0
        return self.dist(self.locations[i - 1], self.locations[j - 1])


distance = Distances()


# l0-distance to add order constraints
class Order:
    def __call__(self, i, j):
        return 0 if i == j else 1


order = Order()

search_parameters = pywrapcp.RoutingModel.DefaultSearchParameters()
search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.ALL_UNPERFORMED)

search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.SIMULATED_ANNEALING
search_parameters.time_limit_ms = 3000

routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(len(distance), 1)

routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(distance)
routing.SetDepot(0)
solver = routing.solver()

routing.AddDimension(order, int(1e18), int(1e18), True, "order")

# Since `ALL_UNPERFORMED` is used, each node must be allowed inactive
order_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie("order")
routing.AddDisjunction([1], int(1e10))
routing.AddDisjunction([2, 3], int(1e10))
routing.AddDisjunction([4], int(1e10))

solver.AddConstraint(
    (routing.ActiveVar(2) == 0)
    or
    (order_dimension.CumulVar(1) <= order_dimension.CumulVar(2))
)
solver.AddConstraint(
    (routing.ActiveVar(3) == 0)
    or
    (order_dimension.CumulVar(1) <= order_dimension.CumulVar(3))
)


solver.AddConstraint(
    (routing.ActiveVar(2) == 0)
    or
    (order_dimension.CumulVar(2) <= order_dimension.CumulVar(4))
)
solver.AddConstraint(
    (routing.ActiveVar(3) == 0)
    or
    (order_dimension.CumulVar(3) <= order_dimension.CumulVar(4))
)

# routing.AddPickupAndDelivery(1, 2)
# routing.AddPickupAndDelivery(1, 3)
# routing.AddPickupAndDelivery(2, 4)
# routing.AddPickupAndDelivery(3, 4)

routing.CloseModelWithParameters(search_parameters)
assignment = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

if assignment is not None:
    print('cost: ' + str(assignment.ObjectiveValue()))
    route = []
    index = routing.Start(0)
    while not routing.IsEnd(index):
        route.append(routing.IndexToNode(index))
        index = assignment.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
    for node in route:
        print(' - {:2d}'.format(node))
else:
    print('nothing found')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@furnon** On github answered my question via the github-issues list: https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/252#issuecomment-249646587

First, constraint programming performs better on tighter constraints, I guess some things are searched for exaustively. In particular, I had to limit the order-dimension:

```py
routing.AddDimension(order, int(1e18), int(1e18), True, "order")
```

is better constrained via

```py
routing.AddDimension(order, len(distance) + 1 ,len(distance) + 1, True, "order")
```

Subsequently, the check on whether `2` or `3` is active is not needed, hence we can simplify the order-constrains like this:

```py
solver.AddConstraint(order_dimension.CumulVar(1) <= order_dimension.CumulVar(2))
solver.AddConstraint(order_dimension.CumulVar(1) <= order_dimension.CumulVar(3))
solver.AddConstraint(order_dimension.CumulVar(2) <= order_dimension.CumulVar(4))
solver.AddConstraint(order_dimension.CumulVar(3) <= order_dimension.CumulVar(4))
```

As I already did in the inline version, but not in the all-code version. Now a feasible solution is returned.